# CSS/JavaScript breaks on Websphere 8.5 server

Tags: javascript, jsp, jakarta-ee, websphere, rational-developer-for-i

We are running Websphere 8.5 on our test server.  We use RAD for development (JSPs/Java EE)and have Websphere 8.5 installed on our local workstations.

A DBA compiles my code and deploys it to the test server.  However, when he did everything was broken in IE.  When I run it on my local machine (server - localhost) everything works fine in both IE and Chrome.  When I use Chrome instead of IE on the test server everything runs fine.  What breaks is mostly some CSS is missing, JavaScript indexOf on an Array is not a known function for the array object, and everything looks really basic, the GO buttons are just little tiny squares that look nothing like they do on my local machine or in Chrome.  I read that indexOf is not compatible with IE version < 9, but everyone mostly runs 10 or 11 here.

Could the test server somehow detect that we are using IE and maybe provide us with a different version of the page?  We are compiling with JDK 1.6  Is there anything that I can tell the DBA to check on the Test server?

Comment: what an imposing block of text that question is - have you heard of the paragraph? Anyway, check that internet exploder isn't in **compatibility mode** for the test server

Comment: Please see [*How do I ask a good question?*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [*How to create a minimal, complete and verifiable example*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Okay.  Well when I went to "Emulation" in the developer tools in IE using the test server it shows that the Document Mode is set to 5 (default), but if I use IE on my local server it's set to Edge.  Can IE detect that it's an older page and try 5 by default?  I don't think the server can set that.

Comment: If CSS is missing on IE, see if the .css file is being loaded into IE - look at the HTTP requests.  It's possible to write IE-specific CSS and it's possible to detect whether or not the user is using IE rather than Chrome.  These sound like front-end issues, not back-end issues.

Answer (score 0):

IE Compatibility Mode has a number of "triggers", including being in particular IE "zones", like "Trusted Sites" or "Intranet", and a "blacklist" maintained by Microsoft.

We saw similar behavior once, with our Development server looking different from our Test and Production servers, because the former was in our company's domain, while the latter in our customer's domain.

Might be a useful link: https://hsivonen.fi/doctype/#iemodes